# Powershell while loop cannot be broken

Tags: powershell

I have a while loop in powershell that checks for input

```
:checker while($choice1 = read-host "Do you want to continue? [Y/N/C]"){
    switch ($choice1){
        "N"{Echo Ok; $temporary = "Exit"; break :checker}
        "Y"{Echo Ok; $temporary = "Continue"; break :checker}
        "C"{Echo Ok; $temporary = "Cancel"; break :checker}
        default{"Invalid input"}
    }
}
```

However, no matter the input, the while loop never gets broken. Is there an issue with my code, or is there a different way to do this that will ensure the correct things to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `break :checker`, you should have `break checker` to break out to the outermost loop. It's just breaking out of the switch statement currently.

Comment: Nicely done; it's unfortunate that optionally using `:` before the label name isn't supported (as of PowerShell 7.0); [this GitHub suggestion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5724) aims to change that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a variant on the idea. it works by setting `$Choice` to the user input ... and, if the input is not valid, setting `$Choice` to a blank string so that the `while` loop will continue.

i removed the call to `ok` since you didn't provide that code. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$Choice = ''
while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
    {
    $Choice = Read-Host 'Do you want to continue? [Y/N/C] '
    switch ($Choice)
        {
        "N"{$temporary = "Exit"; break}
        "Y"{$temporary = "Continue"; break}
        "C"{$temporary = "Cancel"; break}
        default{$Choice = ''; "Invalid input"}
        }
    }

$Choice
$Temporary
```

output ...

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/N/C] : t
Invalid input
Do you want to continue? [Y/N/C] : y
y
Continue
```

Comment: Oops, I meant to do `echo Ok`  not `ok` my bad! I'll fix that in the latest edit

Comment: @Asian - that is an easy-to-make error. [*grin*] does my code work as `a different way` that you asked for?

Comment: glad to hear that it works ... & you are most welcome! [*grin*]